# Integrating tailwindcss with django

Tags: django, tailwind-css

am trying to integrate tailwindcss with django. django seems to have located my tailwindcss and even the default font for tailwindcss is implemented, but none of the tailwind classes seems to work in my project.
What could be the reason why?

I tried passing classes mx-auto, font-semibold into my div [as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPkAX.png) but both the classes failed to respond [as seen in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt2Dt.png)

And when i tried to add another css property (background-color:blue) in the tailwind output file, that property works.

So the question is, how comes other css properties work but tailwind classes won work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a problem in your `tailwind.config.js` since TailwindCSS doesn't update the output CSS file according to your changes. So make sure the `content` section of your `tailwind.config.js` file is correct.

From the documentation:

> The `content` section of your `tailwind.config.js` file is where you configure the paths to all of your HTML templates, JavaScript components, and any other source files that contain Tailwind class names.

Learn more about `content` in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).